# How to use Func<T> as an injected property

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, autofac

I am trying to pass Func to the public property of an instance of a class.  Whenever I try to access the property it displays as null.

AutoFac Configuration:

```
builder.RegisterType<Func<BillingStore>>().PropertiesAutowired();
```

Public Property:

```
public static Func<BillingStore> BillingStoreFactory { get; set; }
```

I am not seeing what I am doing wrong, I usually try to avoid delegates but this time I cannot.

Comment: *"pass Func to the public property of an instance of a class"* But the property is defined as `public static`, so its not an instance property...

Answer (score 2):

Define the property without the static keyword

```
public Func<BillingStore> BillingStoreFactory { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 2):

It seems there are a lot of things going on here that may be causing you trouble.

First, lets round out the code example so we have something to talk about. I assume you have something along the lines of this:

```
void Main()
{
    var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
    builder.RegisterType<Func<BillingStore>>().PropertiesAutowired();
    builder.RegisterType<Consumer>();
    var container = builder.Build();
    var consumer = container.Resolve<Consumer>();

    // The BillingStoreFactory property is null here
    // but you want it populated.
}

public class BillingStore { }

public class Consumer
{
  public static Func<BillingStore> BillingStoreFactory { get; set; }
}
```

**Problem 1: You're using a static property. Make it an instance property.** IoC containers like Autofac work on instance parameters and properties, not statics. Your `BillingStoreFactory` property needs to be an instance property.

```
public class Consumer
{
  public Func<BillingStore> BillingStoreFactory { get; set; }
}
```

**Problem 2: You're setting `PropertiesAutowired` on the wrong object. Set it on the consumer.** The point of `PropertiesAutowired` is to say, "When I resolve this object, I want you to also inject its properties." Right now you have that on the function/factory, so Autofac is going to try to inject properties *on* `Func<BillingStore>`, not properties *of type* `Func<BillingStore>`. You want the property to be populated on the thing *with the property* - the consuming object.

```
builder.RegisterType<Consumer>().PropertiesAutowired();
```

**Problem 3: Your function registration won't work.** If you do a `RegisterType<T>` call, it implies that Autofac is going to be able to automatically figure out the parameters for `T` - either it doesn't take any constructor parameters or Autofac will have enough information to fill those in.

`Func<T>` doesn't have a parameter-less constructor. If you were to type `new Func<BillingStore>(` in VS, you'd see IntelliSense show you that the constructor actually takes an object and an `IntPtr`. I'm guessing you don't have that registered in your container.

I'm further guessing that what you *really* wanted to do was use the built-in [`Func<T>` relationship type that Autofac provides for you](http://autofac.readthedocs.org/en/latest/resolve/relationships.html#dynamic-instantiation-func-b) rather than a factory you're creating. **If you want the Autofac `Func<T>`, you only need to register the type in the function.** Magic happens. It just works. In this case, that means you just need to register `BillingStore` and make sure it can be resolved.

```
builder.RegisterType<BillingStore>();
```

**If we put it all together, the updated code looks like this:**

```
void Main()
{
    var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
    builder.RegisterType<BillingStore>();
    builder.RegisterType<Consumer>().PropertiesAutowired();
    var container = builder.Build();
    var consumer = container.Resolve<Consumer>();

    // The BillingStoreFactory property is now populated
    // on the Consumer object you resolved.
}

public class BillingStore { }

public class Consumer
{
  public Func<BillingStore> BillingStoreFactory { get; set; }
}
```

**I'd recommend reading up on the [implicit relationship types](http://autofac.readthedocs.org/en/latest/resolve/relationships.html) and [property injection support](http://autofac.readthedocs.org/en/latest/register/prop-method-injection.html) in Autofac.** We have a lot of documentation with examples that can help you work through this.